# Is Blazor (.Net core 3.1) partial class equivalent to `@inject ViewModel`?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

The default Blazor scaffolded code mixed the C# code with the markup code in the .razor file.

In this video https://brianlagunas.com/lets-learn-blazor-mvvm-with-blazor/, it introduced MVVM for blazor. In the .razor file, you will just need to add the followng two lines.

```
@using ViewModels
@inject ViewModel1 ViewModel
```

The C# class `ViewModels.ViewModel1` is the ViewModel class. And the .razor can bind the [parameter] properties.

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel1
    {
        [parameter]
        ....
```

Now .Net 3.1 Blazor added partial class, you just need to create a partial class with the same name of the Blazor component. And the Razor markup can bind to the properties of C# partial class.

Are these two essential the same thing?

Comment: The partial class feature in Blazor essentially allows a “code-behind” which you may know from WinForms or WPF.

Comment: You shouldn't try too hard to apply full-fledged MVVM into web applications. In WPF MVVM (thats what MVVM was first invented for, for WPF binding capabilities) you were supposed to put presentation logic into the ViewModel and notifications of property changes. (`INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICommand`) neither of which apply to html. ViewModels in Webapplications are closer to ViewModels in MVC, they are just mere DTOs, bring data into a specific shape, that makes it easy for the view to consume.

Comment: You seen in that linked video that binding component paramenters doesnt work and adding a property just to "pass by" the binding to the lower class is just redundant code (that was exactly the point that `INotifyPropertyChanged`was try to solve in WPF's MVVM)

Comment: So using the new partial class should be preferred over the MVVM approach in the video?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `@code {}` block in the .razor file and the code-behind `partial` class can do the same things but have different syntax.

You can use the C# `Inject` attribute in the code-behind `partial` class:

```cs
[Inject]
public ViewModel1 ViewModel { get; set; }
```